# Getting "requestFeature() must be called before adding content" when performed requestFeature

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

For some reason I am getting the exception 
"android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content"

on the following command:

```
        useTitleFeature = window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

Kinda doesn't make any sense.

Add that to the fact that it depends where I call it from.
If I call the method that contains it from the onCreate then it is ok.
However, if I call the method  from the "onPostExecute" of an AsyncTask then it doesn't work.
If I skip the command it still lets me do setContent.
It's only this command that it doesn't like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put that command before the `setContentView(R.layout.main);`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is before. That's what is so weird.

Comment: Just to check I will add an override for setContentView and stop it there. See if I am setting it someone else without realising.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call this line BEFORE setting the content view (calling the `setContentView` method)